# copy constructor does initialize primitive data types

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
        int a;
};
int main()
{
        Foo f;
        Foo f1(f);
        cout<<f.a;
        return 0;
}
```

Here f.a prints garbage value but when we add f1.a then both f.a and f1.a is initialized with 0.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
        int a;
};
int main()
{
        Foo f;
        Foo f1(f);
        cout<<f.a<<f.b;
        return 0;
}
```

Please help me to understand what is the reason behind this.

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile. Please show real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninitialized variables have indeterminate values, i.e. whatever happened to be in that memory. `0` is one of possible indeterminate values, as well as any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Copy c-tor does not initialize primitive data types as long as you don't explicitly declare it. 
Value of uninitialized variable is determined by RAM space value which belongs to this variable, so it could be anything. But it's more likely that this ram was set to 0 (after computer restart probably).

Comment: Not because of restart. Whenever OS allocates memory to a process, it has to fill it with `0` so that sensitive information from other processes that used this physical memory before does not leak.